# Why is the spectrum of the identity operator on a normed space X is equal to its point spectrum.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $I$ be the identity operator on a normed space $X$. I know that $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue of $I$. But why is $\lambda=1$ is the only spectral value of $I$? What about the residual spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda\ne1$, then $I-\lambda I=(1-\lambda) I$ is invertible, with inverse $S=\frac1{1-\lambda}\,I$. So any $\lambda\ne1$ is in the resolvent, and $\sigma(I)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Residual spectrum also contains those λ‘s for which I - λ I is invertible. So is there any chance that for some λ, the domain of resolvent R(T; λ) is not dense in X?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If $T-\lambda I$ is invertible, then $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $T$. The residual spectrum are those $\lambda$ such that $T-\lambda I$ is injective and its range is **not** dense.

Comment: Ohhh…now I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)